# ASP.NET Core 3.0 in Docker : Seeding DB hangs intermittently on stage, but never in dev

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I am struggling with one of our dotnet core 3.0 apps reliably seeding the database on app startup.  In a nutshell, the issue is we run a data seeding method on app startup to run migrations and seed data.  It's working fine in DEV, but it intermittently hangs on UAT / PRD.  Here are some facts about the application and things that I have tried:

- The API is an ASP.NET Core 3.0 app and the front-end is Angular 7
- The app, as well as related services are all dockerized into containers.
- In DEV + UAT, we do not persist the database in a persisted volume, when we down/up the containers, the database is recreated / reseeded.  In PRD, obviously, we have a persisted volume.
- We run containers for the Web API, SqlServer 2017, Elasticsearch, Nginx, and Kibana (all linux).  We use the same Dockerfiles in DEV / UAT / PRD environments, with config settings dynamically applied.
- We upgraded the app from dotnet core 2.1 to 3.0 about 2-3 months ago and everything is working fine, except the seeding.
- Data seeding methods use the bulk insert extension methods for EF Core 3.1.1 which I added recently thinking it would help with the hanging when seeding on UAT.
- Originally we had calls to our `DbInitializer` class in `Configure` in Startup.cs.. I subsequently moved it out of `Configure` (see next point)
- I moved the seed calls in `DbInitializer` to a `HostedService` in an attempt to remedy the situation.  I suspected that because all of our seed methods are async, calling them in `Configure` may be the issue since it's not async, and I read it could cause task deadlocks.  The Hosted Service I created is fully async and again all of my methods in `DbInitializer` are also async.
- I am aware of the `HasData()` method of seeding in EF Core 2.1+, but my understanding was that this is good for 'simple' seeding, so we opted for the alternative approach.
- I had a suspicion that maybe the issue was SQL Server inside of the docker container, so as a test I pointed it to an on-prem instance of SQL Server 2017 running in our environment, made no difference.
- I have quadruple checked `DbInitializer` for any calls that are being called synchronously, there are none, everything is properly awaited and calling the correct async method.
- When the seeding hangs, there are no errors, the app log output just stops at the 'begin' log entry and never comes online.  I've checked the db logs, again, nothing.
- After the seeding hangs, if I restart the Asp.Net Core docker container via `docker restart {containerID}` the seeding will typically (~95% of the time) succeed, and the app becomes available immediately.

**Here's what the app's logs looks like when the seeding hangs:**

```
[19:10:14 INF] MyApp.App is starting...
[19:10:18 INF] Program :: Checking if DB is ready...
[19:10:20 INF] Start installing Hangfire SQL objects...
[19:10:20 INF] Hangfire SQL objects installed.
[19:10:21 WRN] No XML encryptor configured. Key {29fcce48-c9a9-4635-979f-870377ed8604} may be persisted to storage in unencrypted form.
[19:10:23 INF] DbInitializer :: Initializing DB...
[19:10:23 INF] DbInitializer :: Applying Migrations...
[19:10:26 INF] DbInitializer :: Finished DB Initialization!!!
[19:10:26 INF] DbInitializer :: Ensuring Seed Data...
[19:10:26 INF] Seed Data: Add Roles Begin
[19:10:27 INF] Seed Data: Add Roles Success
[19:10:27 INF] Seed Data: Add Countries Begin
[19:10:28 INF] Seed Data: Add Countries Success
[19:10:28 INF] Seed Data: Add Provinces Begin
[19:10:28 INF] Seed Data: Add Provinces Success
[19:10:28 INF] Seed Data: Add Users Begin
[19:10:29 INF] Seed Data: Add Users Success
[19:10:29 INF] Seed Data: Add Orgs Begin
[19:10:29 INF] Seed Data: Add Orgs Success
[19:10:29 INF] Seed Data: Add UserProfile Begin
[19:10:29 INF] Seed Data: Add UserProfile Success
[19:10:29 INF] Seed Data: Add Studies Begin
[19:10:29 INF] Seed Data: Add Studies Success
[19:10:29 INF] Seed Data: Add StudyStatements Begin
```

**Here is the log output of a successful seeding, which again *always* succeeds on my dev machine in Visual Studio, and roughly 50% of the time on UAT:**

```
[19:12:35 INF] MyApp.App is starting...
[19:12:36 INF] Program :: Checking if DB is ready...
[19:12:38 INF] Start installing Hangfire SQL objects...
[19:12:38 INF] Hangfire SQL objects installed.
[19:12:40 INF] DbInitializer :: Initializing DB...
[19:12:40 INF] DbInitializer :: Finished DB Initialization!!!
[19:12:40 INF] DbInitializer :: Ensuring Seed Data...
[19:12:40 INF] Seed Data: Add Roles Begin
[19:12:41 INF] Seed Data: Add Roles Success
[19:12:41 INF] Seed Data: Add Countries Begin
[19:12:41 INF] Seed Data: Add Countries Success
[19:12:41 INF] Seed Data: Add Provinces Begin
[19:12:41 INF] Seed Data: Add Provinces Success
[19:12:41 INF] Seed Data: Add Users Begin
[19:12:41 INF] Seed Data: Add Users Success
[19:12:41 INF] Seed Data: Add Orgs Begin
[19:12:41 INF] Seed Data: Add Orgs Success
[19:12:41 INF] Seed Data: Add UserProfile Begin
[19:12:41 INF] Seed Data: Add UserProfile Success
[19:12:41 INF] Seed Data: Add Studies Begin
[19:12:42 INF] Seed Data: Add Studies Success
[19:12:42 INF] Seed Data: Add StudyStatements Begin
[19:12:42 INF] Seed Data: Add StudyStatements Success
[19:12:42 INF] Seed Data: Add StudyCodes Begin
[19:12:42 INF] Seed Data: Add StudyCodes Success
[19:12:42 INF] Seed Data: Add StudyStructure Begin
[19:12:42 INF] Seed Data: Add StudyStructure Success
[19:12:42 INF] Seed Data: Add Instances Begin
[19:12:42 INF] Seed Data: Add Instaces Success
[19:12:42 INF] Seed Data: Add PaymentMethod Begin
[19:12:42 INF] Seed Data: Add PaymentMethod Success
[19:12:42 INF] Seed Data: Add Packages Begin
[19:12:43 INF] Seed Data: Add Packages Success
[19:12:43 INF] DbInitializer :: Ensuring Test Data...
[19:12:43 INF] Test Data: Add IdentityUsers Begin
[19:12:43 INF] Test Data: Add IdentityUsers Success
[19:12:43 INF] Test Data: Add UserProfile Begin
[19:12:43 INF] Test Data: Add UserProfile Success
[19:12:43 INF] Test Data: Add Studies Begin
[19:12:43 INF] Test Data: Add Studies Success
[19:12:43 INF] Test Data: Add StudyStatements Begin
[19:12:43 INF] Test Data: Add StudyStatements Success
[19:12:43 INF] Test Data: Add StudyCodes Begin
[19:12:43 INF] Test Data: Add StudyCodes Success
[19:12:43 INF] Test Data: Add StudyStructure Begin
[19:12:43 INF] Test Data: Add StudyStructure Success
[19:12:43 INF] Test Data: Add Instances Begin
[19:12:44 INF] Test Data: Add Instances Success
[19:12:44 INF] Starting Hangfire Server using job storage: 'SQL Server: {redacted}@MyApp'
[19:12:44 INF] Using the following options for SQL Server job storage: Queue poll interval: 00:00:15.
[19:12:44 INF] Using the following options for Hangfire Server:
    Worker count: 20
    Listening queues: 'default'
    Shutdown timeout: 00:00:15
    Schedule polling interval: 00:00:15
[19:12:44 INF] AppConfigure :: Trying to ensure valid DB connection for MyAppDbContext
[19:12:44 INF] AppConfigure :: MyAppDbContext DB connection was successful in 0.0569003s!
[19:12:44 INF] Starting IdentityServer4 version 3.0.0.0
[19:12:44 INF] You are using the in-memory version of the persisted grant store. This will store consent decisions, authorization codes, refresh and reference tokens in memory only. If you are using any of those features in production, you want to switch to a different store implementation.
[19:12:44 INF] Using the default authentication scheme Identity.Application for IdentityServer
[19:12:44 INF] Starting Hangfire Server using job storage: 'SQL Server: {redacted}@MyApp'
[19:12:44 INF] Using the following options for SQL Server job storage: Queue poll interval: 00:00:15.
[19:12:44 INF] Using the following options for Hangfire Server:
    Worker count: 20
    Listening queues: 'default'
    Shutdown timeout: 00:00:15
    Schedule polling interval: 00:00:15
[19:12:44 INF] Server 49d71a12c49d:1:d6fbae79 successfully announced in 165.7588 ms
[19:12:44 INF] Server 49d71a12c49d:1:3bcc860c successfully announced in 21.242800000000003 ms
[19:12:44 INF] Server 49d71a12c49d:1:3bcc860c is starting the registered dispatchers: ServerWatchdog, ServerJobCancellationWatcher, ExpirationManager, CountersAggregator, Worker, DelayedJobScheduler, RecurringJobScheduler...
[19:12:44 INF] Server 49d71a12c49d:1:d6fbae79 is starting the registered dispatchers: ServerWatchdog, ServerJobCancellationWatcher, ExpirationManager, CountersAggregator, Worker, DelayedJobScheduler, RecurringJobScheduler...
```

**In `ConfigureServices` I have this entry for my HostedService:**

```
services.AddHostedService<DataInitHostedService>();
```

**The code for my hosted service looks like this:**

```
 public class DataInitHostedService : IHostedService
    {
        private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;
        public DataInitHostedService(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
        }

        public async Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            using (var scope = _serviceProvider.CreateScope())
            {
                var dbInitalizaer = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<DbInitializer>();

                await dbInitalizaer.DoSeeding();
            }
        }

        public Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken) => Task.CompletedTask;
    }
```

**The `DbInitializer` class is large, so I will only post the main init method that migrates the database, as well as a sample seed method:**

```
 public async Task Initialize()
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("DbInitializer :: Initializing DB...");

            var pendingMigrations = await _dbContext.Database.GetPendingMigrationsAsync();
            if (pendingMigrations.Any())
            {
                _logger.LogInformation("DbInitializer :: Applying Migrations...");
                await _dbContext.Database.MigrateAsync();
            }

            _logger.LogInformation("DbInitializer :: Finished DB Initialization!!!");
        }
        //there's a series of methods that look very similar to this which performs the seeding
        // The List<T> parameters are manually created in code and passed to the relevant methods
        //  The Seed() method asynchronously awaits each one of the methods that looks like this, for 
        // each entity that we're seeding
        private async Task AddUserProfilesAsync(List<UserProfile> userProfiles)
        {
            List<UserProfile> filteredList = new List<UserProfile>();
            foreach (UserProfile profile in userProfiles)
            {
                if (await _dbContext.UserProfiles.FirstOrDefaultAsync(u => u.Id == profile.Id) == null)
                {
                    filteredList.Add(profile);
                }
            }

            await _dbContext.BulkInsertAsync(filteredList, new BulkConfig { SetOutputIdentity = true, 
                 PreserveInsertOrder = true });
        }
```

Here are the questions I have, in addition to the obvious question 'Why the hell does this intermittently hang?':

- I am perplexed that there are no runtime exceptions or log entries that would indicate an issue.  Is it possible that I am missing something, like perhaps a config or setting that would be supressing the log entry?  I mean, in my experience, if a runtime error occurs, I can see it in the logs easily.. this just hangs, as per my example log paste above..
- Has anyone experienced this with dotnet core 3 where during app startup it just hangs like this without any meaningful feedback?  Any tips / suggestions?
- Is the approach that we're taking the issue?  Should we be seeding differently?  As mentioned above, I do know about the `HasData` method for EfCore builder, just everything I read indicated it was good for small seeding.  Is the approach we're taking the issue?  Keep in mind that the seeding is happening in an async HostedService, which I thought was better than synchronously in Startup => `Configure`..  thoughts?

Any help or suggestions would **GREATLY** appreciated... I'm bald, and I am considering growing my hair back just so I can pull it out, that's how frustrated I am :)  Lol, seriously, any tips / help would be great!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Repro the hang with while using SQL Profiler against the database, and check for blocked requests in sys.dm_exec_requests.  Also add EF Core Logging: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/logging?tabs=v3

Comment: Thanks @DavidBrowne-Microsoft I did check for block requests in SSMS by using the Activity Monitor (while seeding was running), and found no requests being blocked by other processes.  I did try to enable EF Core specific logging, but my SQL statements that EF generates never show up in the logs.  I've done exhaustive testing using examples on how to enable EF core logging, but nothing works.  In my searching, I've found others complaining that logging just doesn't work for EF Core 3.0. 

Realistically, I should get a runtime exception anyway, no?